# Undefined error: create object with function that returns HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, scope, undefined

I am just getting into Javascript, so this is almost certainly a newbie question. I'm trying to create an object in the following way:

```
var canvas = {
    element: function(){ return document.getElementById("bounceCanvas"); },
    centerX: element().width / 2,
    centerY: element().height / 2,
};
```

However, I get "SCRIPT5009: 'element' is undefined " using the IE debugger.

The object declaration is close to the top of the module. I know that it can take a while for the HTML elements to load, so instead of just saying:

```
element: document.getElementById("bounceCanvas");
```

I have tried to use a function that will return the element so that each call to `canvas.element()` will make a new attempt to retrieve it from the page. Why is `element()` always un-defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` to refer current object and then indicate the function otherwise the function will get undefined on another property for another property's function:

```
var canvas = {
    element: function(){ return document.getElementById("bounceCanvas"); },
    centerX: this.element().style.width / 2,
    centerY: this.element().style.height / 2,
};
```

Comment: what is this, can you explain?

Comment: Thanks C-link. Some progress, but now I get "Object doesn't support property or method 'element' "

Comment: I'm trying to return the width/height of the HTML element. It should be a defined property of the element that I return with canvas.element(), no? Maybe it's because I'm from a different programming background, but object.method().propertyofobjectreturnedbymethod should be valid, isn't it?

Comment: this.element().style.width should work... you may also check getComputedStyle google that...

Comment: Thanks for your help C-link. Still can't get it to work, but you answered the original question